# How to send images in Telegram uncompressed and by default

Tags: default-settings, telegram-messenger

I often send images to friends. Unfortunately, Telegram tries to compress the image every time when I send this image, even though I prefer uncompressed images. I found a solution to send the image as an uncompressed file, but it is not comfortable because every when I send an image, I have to untick the same setting. The problem is that Telegram does not remember that I prefer sending uncompressed images. There isn't even a setting to always send images uncompressed.
So, every time I send an image, I have to untick the 'send uncompressed' setting, and it is already making me angry because it consumes too much time.
Please, help me with the solution to make Telegram remember my choice and never ask me again.
I just want to send images in their original size every time. I don’t want to untick every time.
PS every time I send one photo at a time, so my question is not about a big group of files at the same time. [image]